# Is there a danger for "permanent fatigue" if [CO2] approaches or exceeds 800 ppm?

Tags: breathing, public-health, air-quality

It is well-known that this century, [CO2-concentrations could rise to 800 ppm and higher](https://yaleclimateconnections.org/2019/06/data-from-earths-past-holds-a-warning-for-our-future-under-climate-change/). It is equally well-known how this relates to a warming climate, rising sea-level and ocean acidification. On the other hand, during the covid-era we learned that CO2-concentration of 800 ppm or higher is indicative of bad air quality: exposing humans to such a concentration or a higher concentration for a couple of hours will in itself apparently lead to fatigue, drowsiness, head ache etc [[1](https://betterhumans.pub/feeling-tired-and-unproductive-it-might-be-co%E2%82%82-89c49c546fd9),[2](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3548274/),[3]](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/26502459/).

Naively "connecting the dots" would suggest that with the trend of increasing CO2-concentration in the Earth's atmosphere, we run a risk of 'burdening' the future generations of humans with permanent fatigue? But to my knowledge, such a warning is not (prominently?) included in, say, the latest IPCC reports?

EDIT: to address a concern expressed by Bryan Krause in the comments, consider also [this publication](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41893-019-0323-1) (which avoids a particular individual as an author and seems to deal with my question straight away)

Comment: Could you please cite a scientific study/report detailing that *"exposing humans to such a concentration [800ppm] or a higher concentration for a couple of hours will in itself apparently lead to fatigue, drowsiness, head ache etc"*?

Comment: Related: https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/50756/does-a-400ppm-ambient-co2-increase-result-in-a-21-decline-in-cognitive-function and https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/24392/how-does-intelligence-or-general-cognitive-ability-vary-with-level-of-co%E2%82%82/ - as I mention in the comments there, there is a particular author with some very suspicious work in this area; both of your citations involve that author. Also 2012 and 2016 are very much not "the covid-era".

Comment: @BryanKrause: I'll look into it. When I say that we 'learned' something during the covid era I mean this in the sense of popular awareness, not the publication date of this or that paper.

Comment: I removed the discussion of the CO2/virus transmission link, as the conversation was getting a bit heated and it's at most tangentially related to the question being asked. As I understand it, some have suggested using indoor CO2 levels as an indication of poor ventilation that could make transmission of airborne viruses more likely.